# Postgres query with time zone

Tags: postgresql, date, timezone, psql

I have table of companies where each company has individual timezone.
for example -
company 1 has time zone UTC+10 and
company 2 - UTC+2

table `companies` has field time_zone and stored abbreviation of zone like `America/Los_Angeles`(I can add additional field for store offset value from UTC if need).

and has table requests with start_date field where stored TIMESTAMP without time zone(UTC-0)
for example -

```
id | company_id | start_date (utc-0)
------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 21-03-16 02-00      // added for company  `21-03-16 12-00`
2  | 2          | 21-03-16 23-00      // added for company  `22-03-16 01-00`
3  | 1          | 20-03-16 13-00      // added for company  `20-03-16 23-00`
4  | 1          | 21-03-16 23-00      // added for company  `22-03-16 09-00
```

I want select records that started from 21-03-16 00-00 to 21-03-16 23-59 considering time zone each company.

but if I will use -

`select * from request where start_date between '2016-03-21 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-03-21 23:59:59.999999'`

I get requests where id = 2 and 4.

but these requests were added 22-03-16 by fact for each company.

Any suggestions how I can decide this situation by one select? Many thanks.

Comment: Like `request.start_date AT TIME ZONE companies.time_zone BETWEEN '2016-03-21 00:00:00Z' AND '2016-03-21 23:59:59.999999Z'`? OFC this will only work, when every row have a PostgreSQL accepted time zone in `time_zone`. You can define a check constraint, like `CHECK ((timestamp '2000-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE time_zone) IS NOT NULL)` to validate `time_zone`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, you might need to clarify.

But I'd say that joining with `companies` where the time zone information is stored should solve the problem:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM request r
   JOIN companies c ON c.id = r.company_id
WHERE r.start_date BETWEEN '2016-03-21 00:00:00.000000'
                           AT TIME ZONE c.time_zone
                       AND '2016-03-21 23:59:59.999999'
                           AT TIME ZONE c.time_zone;
```